# WPML - 404 Error when I try to pass GET parameters in my "different languages in directories" installation

Tags: 404-error, multi-language, plugin-wpml

I'm using **WPML** installation with the **languages in different directories**. But I'm trying to pass some `_$GET` parameters to the url and I'm getting the 404 error.

I'm passing the `_$GET` parameters with a link. Just like this:

```
$link_aqui_se_sirve = get_permalink( get_page_by_path('donde') );
$taxonomia_estados = get_terms('estados');

foreach ( $taxonomia_estados as $tax ) :
     $nombre_estado = $tax->name;
     $link = $link_aqui_se_sirve.'?'.$establecimientos_cpt_name.'='.$tax->slug;
     <a href="<?php echo $link; ?>"><?php echo $some_name; ?></a>
endforeach;
```

I'm getting correctly the url, example: `site.com/es/donde/?establecimiento=oaxaca` but I get the 404 error.

I've used this way before, in other site (no multilingual) and works good. Any idea to solve it? Thanks!

Comment: I think the issue stems from using your CPT name as a GET param. WordPress creates query vars for custom post types. Essentially this request is telling WordPress to get the `establecimientos` with the name or ID `oaxaca`. Unless you have a post that happens to have a slug that is the same as that tax slug this will give you a 404. Does this work if you use a different name for your GET param?

Comment: Thanks a lot @mtinsley, you are right. I didn't know about the query vars for cpt. If I change my GET param to different name, all works correctly. Could you post it like an answer to give you the bounty, or there is a way to give you manually in the comment? Thank you very much, you save me a lot time!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem your GET param is using the same name as the query var for your custom post type.

```
$link = $link_aqui_se_sirve.'?'.$establecimientos_cpt_name.'='.$tax->slug;
```

With that URL, WordPress is expecting the value of the `$establecimientos_cpt_name` parameter to be a post slug. Instead you are giving it a taxonomy slug. This will give you a 404 unless you have a post that happens to have the same slug as your taxonomy.

If you are setting this parameter for your own purposes, you should choose a name that does not collide with WordPress' internal request processing.